# Powershell website automating button click on login

Tags: powershell, button, authentication, web, automation

So I'm new to powershell. I've built a few scripts for fun but got stuck on one that I don't seem to be able to figure out. I'm trying to automate the clicking of the "Continue" button but don't know what to do. I have tried everything I can think of. Any ideas?

```
$username='username' 
$password='password'

$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true
$ie.Navigate("https://www.ksl.com/public/member/signin?login_forward=%2F")

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){Start-Sleep -seconds 1;}   

$usernamefield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('memberemail')
$usernamefield.value = $username

$passwordfield = $ie.Document.getElementByID('memberpassword')
$passwordfield.value = $password

$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.type -eq "continue"}
$Link.click()
```

Comment: There should be has a newline between $username='username' and $password='password'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the object's Type is Image, not continue. The ClassName is continue. Try this line in that code and see if that works for you:

```
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.className -eq "continue"}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I see what you mean and where I messed up. TY for your help!

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark the answer as the solution so that future users can use this as reference.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$ie.Document.getElementByID('dado_form_3').submit()
```