# System hangs in between running a powershell script.

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate to extract data from a webpage after clicking on a button. But when I try to execute, the system freezes and it requires hard reboot. Please refer the code below.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject Internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate("http://beta.speedtest.net")
while($ie.readystate -ne 4) {
sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
$link = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span") |Where-Object {$_.innertext -like "Begin test"}
$link.click()
```

Reference: [Powershell website automating button click on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768353/powershell-website-automating-button-click-on-login)`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in there which would cause a system freeze.
As you are starting an Internet Explorer instance, I guess IE is crashing your system and it is unreleated to your script or powershell. 
You can verify by running the script on another machine.
Then I would try reinstalling IE on the crashing machine.